# Multiple Applications in one android apk

Tags: android

I have two 3 story books as separate projects. I want to run all three from single apk. On launching application user can select any one of the three books within the app. I have attached a launching activity screen shot.

Comment: you can use package maanager and ask user to insall ur app[3 supporting app] , u can keep apk in assert in ur Main apk

Comment: What's wrong with creating a main activity that presents three image buttons to choose from and each launches its own book?

Comment: Hi Eran, Each button launches different book which were developed as seperate project.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not packaging three apps into a single apk, but packaging one app with three sets of resources (books).  It's hard to be more specific without knowing what format your books are or how you want to present them, but the general logic would be:

1. Package the three books in resources in your one app
2. Create one main activity, which allows the user to chose a book
3. Upon selection, launch a "reading" activity loading the selected book from the resources